# Issue with preventing multiple entries in to the table in stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure for inserting few details in to the database using a PHP page. It should enter the data only if there are no similar data entry in the table. I tried to test it by making 100 requests together (using a testing tool). But 4 times the same row is present after the execution.

Here is the stored procedure I am using:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AddCreditCard`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddCreditCard`(IN scardname VARCHAR(200),scardnumber VARCHAR(200),scardedate VARCHAR(200),scardcvv VARCHAR(200),scountry VARCHAR(200),sdeviceid TEXT,scard_type VARCHAR(200),OUT rflag INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE user_id INT DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE card_count INT DEFAULT -1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    SET rflag=0;
    SELECT udd_user_id_fk INTO user_id FROM user_device_details WHERE udd_device_id=sdeviceid;
    IF user_id<>0 THEN
        SELECT COUNT(uccd_entry_id) INTO card_count FROM user_credit_card_details WHERE uccd_card_number=scardnumber AND uccd_user_id_fk=user_id;
        IF card_count=0 THEN

            INSERT INTO user_credit_card_details(uccd_user_id_fk,uccd_card_name,uccd_card_number,uccd_card_expiry_date,uccd_card_cvv,uccd_country,uccd_card_type)VALUES(user_id,scardname,scardnumber,scardedate,scardcvv,scountry,scard_type);
            SET rflag=1;
        ELSE
            SET rflag=414;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        SET rflag=0;
    END IF;
    COMMIT; 
 END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The result I am expecting is that, at first it should return '1' and for all the requests after that it should return '414'. Kindly suggest me a solution for this issue.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use stored procedures to achieve this? It seems to me this could be easily solved using a unique index on (uccd_card_number,uccd_user_id) and foreign key constraints to ensure a user row exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple lines after `IF` and before `THEN`, you need to enclose them in a `BEGIN...END` block.